# having trouble converting from String to byte[]

Tags: java, string, arrays, bufferedreader, valueconverter

```
public static Runnable reader() throws IOException {
    Log.e("Communication", "reader");
    din = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    brdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(din), 300);
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
        try {
            char[] buffer = new char[200];
            int anzahlZeichen = brdr.read(buffer, 0, 200);
            String nachricht = new String(buffer, 0, anzahlZeichen);
            byte[] in = nachricht.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
            for (int counter = 0; counter < nachricht.length(); counter++) {
                System.out.println(in);
            }
            if (nachricht != null)
                answer();
            System.out.println(nachricht);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            done = true;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

i want to convert the String `nachricht` to the Byte[] `in` but i dont get it. Could anyone help pls? I am just receiving Numbers, no words or letters. Another method is welcome, too. All i get at `System.out.println(nachricht)`is seven times`[B@41c04778` but i should get `01 02 03 04 05 06 07`.

Comment: You shouldn't use variable names from different languages in the same project; be consistent, that'll make your code easier to read.

Comment: thx G.Bach, i will do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is line`System.out.println(in)`

It should be `System.out.println(in[counter]);`

Answer (score 2):

This

```
[B@41c04778
```

indicates you're printing an array (**[**) of bytes (**B**).

Java arrays don't have a useful `toString()` implementation. The above is useful to understand since you'll do the same in the future. Obvious mnemonics exist for other primitive types.